# how to install throttle module in python3 using terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, throttling, pypandoc

I am working on web scraping. while reading an e-book I came across this Throttle Module .

It wanted me to import following module : 
from **chp1.throttle import Throttle**

It is showing me the error suggesting that the chp1 module does not exist.

I tried installing throttle using the following code :

> pip install python-throttle

**which gave me this following error :**

> Collecting python-throttle
>
> Downloading python-throttle-0.1.5.tar.gz

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-E7Y4WF/python-throttle/setup.py", line 1, in <module>


 import pypandoc

ImportError: No module named pypandoc


----------------------------------------
```

Command

> python setup.py egg_info

failed with error code 1 in **/tmp/pip-build-E7Y4WF/python-throttle/**

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: `pip install pypandoc`

Comment: got this error after installing pypandoc and installing throttle : 
 raise OSError("No pandoc was found: either install pandoc and add it\n" 
    OSError: No pandoc was found: either install pandoc and add it
    to your PATH or or call pypandoc.download_pandoc(...) or
    install pypandoc wheels with included pandoc.
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tcLUXZ/python-throttle/

Comment: Run the terminal with Admin privileges. I get similar errors when `pip` installing with normal user privileges. I also add the `Lib` and the `Scripts` folder to PATH, just so Python could easily search for packages. Your last resort will be to build pandoc with wheel or via `pypandoc`. Here is the official [pandoc donwnload](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypandoc) page.

Comment: thanks i solved the issue... but now facing another issue while using the following command : sudo apt-get python-throttle                                                   Error : python-throttle requires Python '>=3.4' but the running Python is 2.7.12 ....                                                                                       i currently have  python 3.5.2 installed.

Comment: try using `sudo pip3 install python-throttle`

Comment: Thank you very much ... Issue has been resolved :D